# Xcode source automatic formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, svn, formatting

I know a very similar question to this was asked, but that was over a year and a half ago. Things change in that time-span, especially with the release of Xcode 4 upon us.

My colleague and I are working on building a library in Objective-C for use on the iPhone, and possibly Mac OSX (at a later date). We both work on it, but I do the majority of the code. Frequently he will implement something and then hand it off to me. He'll work on something else, and then I will extend the functionality of what he wrote. He has preferences for his code such as leaving opening method brackets on their own line, but I prefer them on the same line as the method signature. There are other differences, but I won't get into them here. Is there some integrated tool or even an external tool I can run after I check his code out of the repository to change the style to my own? Or even better, can this be automated for each of us so that upon opening the file it will be formatted to our liking so that only the files we touch are flagged as being changed by our source control program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a link](http://hackertoys.com/2008/09/18/adding-a-code-beautifier-script-to-xcode/) that should help me with this. I think the solution will probably be for both my colleague and I to have separate scripts we run to format the code to our liking.

Comment: You can now install [Uncrustify](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode) through [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io).

Answer (score 2):

I think when it comes down to it, you will both have to agree on a coding style.  Going through the version history of files that are formatted you to each user's liking is going to turn into a nightmare if you need to diff files at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you have to agree on between yourselves.

It will definitely hamper diffing files later on and needs to be hammered out now.

Flip a coin, rock paper scissors, whatever, but agree to one style and stick to it.

Other things you need to set in stone are tabs vs. spaces, variable naming, method naming and comments. Oh and don't forget about line wrapping and alignment/indenting. Its very annoying diffing a file and finding 90% of the changes are tabs vs. spaces or braces on their own line after a function declaration.

Because I work with a lot of different people on multiple projects I often put a small comment with a note explaining why I did whatever, after my "short" name.

Months later someone else can see who did that code and why it is the way it is, or if they have questions they can see who did it and track me down.

Answer (score 1):

For additional formatting of Objective-C in Xcode check out [Xcode 4 Uncrustify](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Xcode-4-Uncrustify-Automator-Services)